# How to install missing commands on Android adb shell?

Tags: python, android, curl, adb, emulation

I want to run curl commands on android adb shell
but curl command is not there
how to install the curl command in android or do we have any other ways to get response for some particular urls ?

```
platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

platform-tools/adb shell curl
/system/bin/sh: curl: inaccessible or not found
```

Comment: Busybox may have curl

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried to install busybox as well but busybox doesn't contain curl

Comment: In general you just need a `curl` compiled for Android and cpu armv7/armv8a. Usually Busybox contains curl, just just have to change the command from `adb shell curl` to `adb shell busybox curl` as the curl command is not a separate binary in busybox.